# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor seleccionado en un select de HTML con PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy creando un CRUD CON PHP, Al dar clic en un botón de editar, me arroja un modal donde tengo un select de html, este select trae todos los datos de una BD, pero quiero que al abrir el modal me arroje el que tiene el registro en su Base de datos, y todos los demás. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 <?php foreach ($topicAdmin as $topicAdmins) { ?>
   <option name="id_pregunta" id="id_pregunta" value="<?php  echo $topicAdmins['id_topic']; ?>"> <?php  echo $topicAdmins['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

No en puedo comprender que le hace falta, me podrian ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuación la lógica para que la adaptes a tu código como esta el flujo:
Lo primero es que obtengas el valor actual que tiene en la BD es el actual seleccionado; (aquí de ejemplo usare nombre de variables que acostumbro) le pondremos
`$valorSeleccionado`.
Como ya tienes un foreach mantendremos ese para el ejemplo; ahora va el código/lógica.

```
<?php

/* Tu proceso para obtener el valor seleccionado */
$valorSeleccionado = /* Asignamos a esta variable el valor seleccionado */

foreach ($topicAdmin as $topicAdmins) { 
?>
   <option name="id_pregunta" id="id_pregunta" value="<?php  echo $topicAdmins['id_topic']; ?>"
<? echo $valorSeleccionado==$topicAdmins['id_topic']?" selected ":"" ?>
><?php  echo $topicAdmins['name']; ?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

La parte que te falta es decidir cuando poner o no el `" selected "` al comparar el valor seleccionado con el del `id` correspondiente al `option` que estas procesando.

En Inglés te puede servir [html select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782373/html-select-option-selected)

Comment: Gracias por responder, en la variable $topicAdmins['id_topic'] no manda solo un id, si no que trae todos los ids de la tabla, esta correcto asi?

Comment: El `foreach` *(https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)* por cada elemento en `$topicAdmin` (asumo) deja en variable `$topicAdmins` solo un elemento (en tu caso deduzco un array asociativo; desde luego por tanto `$topicAdmin` tiene 1 o **N** array asociativos); este elemento contiene solo un valor en cada posición del array. Por tanto no, no tiene (un solo elemento) todos los ids de la tabla; solo uno por vez.

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación, me funciono la lógica que me estableciste, cambie algunas cosas del código por la versión de php, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
<select class="custom-select mb-2" id="forma_cara" name="forma_cara" required>
    <option selected disabled value="">*Selecciona un titulo...   </option>
    <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT id,Valor from rasgos_fisicos where nombreRasgoFisico = "cara"';
    foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row) {
                                                ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Valor']; ?>" <?php echo ($row['valor'] == $forma_cara_ ) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['Valor']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Por cierto, los snippets aquí no funcionan con PHP, solo lo hacen con HTML, CSS y JS. Lee [answer].